# ant: order of execution of "depends" target?

Tags: java, ant, build.xml

if I have

```
<target name="A" depends="B,C"/>
```

is there a deterministic order of execution of targets `B` and `C`? Are they executed one after the other in the order of their appearance in the list, are they executed in parallel? Does `C` wait for `B` to finish?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are executed one after the other. C will not start until B finishes.

Furthermore, the 'if' clause is not checked until after the 'depends' targets are executed.

Answer (score 7):

It's in the order of appearance in the list. See https://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html:

> Ant tries to execute the targets in the depends attribute in the order they appear (from left to right)...